# Improve video encoding quality with Synology DS Photo

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nas, streaming, synology

I've got a Synology NAS box with DS PHOTO where you can upload 1080p videos from your phone or DSLR etc. The result is slow playback but also very bad quality video which I assume is due to using very bad video codecs during the conversion of the uploaded DSLR 1080p video files.

YouTube videos by comparison look much better – even at 480p – compared to the butchery DS PHOTO did to my video. (I usually upload using the Synology Desktop photo/video uploader, not from app.)

Is there a way to fix DS PHOTO or run these conversions manually over SSH to make them look better in 480p/720p/1080p, perhaps using other codecs? My tests were on a Gigabit "local" LAN/network.

Comment: Which Synology Box do you use and where do you play the video then (via browser, media player etc)?